# Paperclip routing error on GET - images showing up as broken 

Tags: paperclip

Im having a strange problem with paperclip in my local development environment.  I seem to be able to upload an image fine because I go to my public folder and the file is indeed there and it is not broken.  However, when I try to see it on my VIEW, the image is broken.  When I view the source, the path leads to the EXACT file location.

So Im wondering, do I need something special to "serve" up these images in my dev environment?  I have read about ImageMagick being required with Paperclip, and so I installed it.  But I never did anything to make them speak to one another (unless this just happens automatically).

The exact error I am getting is:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/system/taskfiles/taskfi
les/000/000/001/original/Forum_announcement_header.jpg"):
```

and so if on my computer I go into my app folder, and then to /public/system/taskfiles/taskfiles......jpg the file is indeed there.

I've searched for answers for HOURS and I can find nobody having this same problem.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you tell how do you include an image into your view?

I had the same problem while I wanted to download the file, but [this article](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2009/8/29/protecting-your-paperclip-downloads) helped me to solve it.

Comment: My problem was that I needed to install ImageMagick correctly so that I could then install the Rmagick gem.  I must say this took me about 8 hours to figure out.  The key for me was installing the DevKit correctly.  The instructions for this were really subpar.  You dont just extract it and leave it at that.  There is actually a process after it that you have to do, and I found those instructions on the DevKit git page.